# How do I hook up a laptop to a Mac monitor?

Tags: windows, mac, display

Is it possible to connect a Windows laptop (Dell XPS) with a Mac monitor (cinema HD display)?

If so, what do I need to make it happen?

Comment: Retagged and added [belongs-on-superuser]. I removed [hdd] since it has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 3):

There is actually no such thing as a "Mac monitor"!

The [Apple Cinema HD Display](http://store.apple.com/au/product/M9179X/A) is just a normal monitor with a DVI input. If your Windows computer (in your case, Dell XPS laptop) has a DVI port (which most do these days), then you can just plug it right in and it should work straight away (assuming you have the graphics power to power such a 'large' display). If your computer does not have DVI-out, then you should be able to pick up a VGA > DVI from a local electronics store for a few bucks.

Answer (score 0):

The Cinema HD should take DVI input. If your laptop is a newer model with a DVI output, you're good to go.

There are USB->DVI adapters, but you're probably not going to get a good result with such a high-res display.

(But the question belongs on SuperUser.com...)

Answer (score 0):

Most Apple displays have a DVI port, which as the other answers note your Dell should also have.

The exception is the newer 24" LED Cinema Display which has a "Mini DisplayPort." You can get an adapter to convert your DVI port to a DisplayPort (a quick Google [came up with this](http://www.atlona.com/Atlona-DVI-to-Mini-DisplayPort-Converter-p-17859.html)).